# PostgreSQL Array Insert Size Limitation Error

Tags: postgresql

I get the following Postgres error:

> ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(1024)

The offending statement is:

```
INSERT INTO integer_array_sensor_data (sensor_id, "time", status, "value") 
VALUES (113, 86651204, 0, '{7302225, 7302161, 7302593, 730211, 
        ... <total of 500 values>... 7301799, 7301896}');
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE integer_array_sensor_data (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    sensor_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "time" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    status INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    "value" INTEGER[] NOT NULL, 
    server_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

Researching PostgreSQL documentation doesn't mention anything about limitation on the array size.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: which type of your Array ?

Comment: Try with PGAdmin3 , dont get any problems.

Comment: The error message is not related to the cited statement. Search in a script for a query updating (inserting to) a table with a column of `varchar(1024)` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem doesn't come from the `Array` itself, but from the `Varchar String` declaring the array values in your `Insert`.  Some drivers type the string literals as `varchar(1024)` causing that issue.

Instead of

```
'{1,2,3}'
```

try using

```
ARRAY[1,2,3]
```

otherwise you can try declaring the type of your string as `TEXT` (unlimited)

```
'{1,2,3}'::text
```

Comment: The string literal is not typed as `varchar(1024)`, and there is no such length limitation for string literals. And an explicit type cast is also not needed in an `INSERT` statement, where the data type is derived from the target column. The question is just as broken as this answer.

Comment: Some drivers do type the string literals as a `varchar(1024)`. It's a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

I start understanding my question although I have not found a solution. Problem is that there is a limitation on the string somewhere library level. I am actually using pqxx and you can't have strings longer than 1024 chars. I have accepted the answer of Guillaume F. because he figured this out but the casting doesn't work. I will edit my reply once I find a solution so people know what to do.

I just tried prepared statements and they have the same limitation.

The workaround is to use COPY or its pqxx binding pqxx:tablewriter.